# In Spring batch can we use the same object of ItemReader in multiple jobs triggered by scheduler in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a scenario where i need to read data from a source. I have created a Custom InputReader as the source sends json data serialized in objects and the return type is an interface. I need to have multiple jobs since the content will vary based on type. For e.g the type may be PlacedOrder or RejectedOrder or CompletedOrder, all of them implement OrderDomain Interface

As per the above example if I may have 3 jobs with 3 different steps but having the same CustomItemReader and the type will be PlacedOrder / RejectedOrder / CompletedOrder as job parameter.
I have a doubt that the "type" derived from JobParameter from StepExecution will have a race condition if the 3 jobs having 3 steps but the same object of the CustomReader. The reader is instantiated in a Configuration class in spring boot like:

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<OrderDomain> orderReader()
{
    return new CustomOrderReader();
}
```

I can create the "type" as global variable to be used in the doRead() method, but I have a doubt whether it will be overwritten by the other thread.

What options do i have? create multiple objects of the CustomReader using @Qualifier and then use them in the respective Steps using the Qualifier?

Requesting you all for the best practice which can be followed here.

Thanks

Comment: Is `CustomOrderReader` thread-safe? That's all it depends on. If it is, you can share it. If it isn't, you need a separate instance for each one (e.g. by making it a prototype bean).

Comment: @Kayaman, no its not. But even if I make it thread-safe, how do I make sure the job parameter is read from BeforeStep -> written to global var -> sync doRead() method reads the variable with the correct value?

Comment: There's no use in making it thread-safe then. You wouldn't want to use global variables and manual syncing.

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman, that's what i wanted to confirm.